# Error de function al intentar ejecutar una funcion importa en Vue js con Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, sweetalert

Actualmente estoy intentando ejecutar una funcion de SweetModal al ejecutar correctamente una llamada de ajax con el siguiente codigo:

```
import { SweetAlertOptions, SweetAlertResult } from "sweetalert2";

 success: function (data) {

     this.$alert(
  "Registro exitoso",
  "Success",
  "success"
).then(() => console.log("Closed"));

 },
```

Si el this.$alert lo pongo fuera del ajax o en otro metodo funciona correctamente pero cuando lo meto dentro de ajax en esa funcion de exito me marca el siguient error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$alert is not a function
```

La libreria que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
https://constkhi.github.io/vue-simple-alert/
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero lo hayas resuelto, sin embargo te coloco dos opciones

Ya que al encapsular la función el this pierde su valor global, tendrías que pasarlo por otro método

1. Declarar una variable self que obtenga los datos de this antes de entrar a axios

```
let self = this;
axios....then(function (data) {
    self.$alert(....)
}
```

2. Hacer uso de arrow functions

```
axios....then(data => {
    this.$alert(...)
}
```